# Ссылки на Viber, Whatsapp, Telegram

Tags: link, href, telegram, whatsapp, viber

Как на сайт вставить ссылки на Viber, Whatsapp и Telegram, при клике на которые открывалось приложение и сразу переходило на чат с указанным номером. Ну и соответственно учитывая мобильные устройства.

С Viber получилось вот так:

```
<a href="viber://forward?text=Номер телефона"</a>
```

Viber открывается он пишет ошибку "Действие не может быть выполнено".

Whatsapp с Telegram открывают программу но молчат вообще

Comment: Телеграм, вроде, поддерживает только ссылки через telegram.me. Почитайте в [официальном FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq#usernames-and-telegram-me) на этот счет. Также можете попробовать через протокол: `tg://resolve?domain=username`.

Answer (score 17):

Для Viber

```
<a href="viber://add?number=номер телефона">
```

телефон в формате +(код страны) номер. + заменить на %2B

Для Telegram

```
<a href="tg://resolve?domain=имя">
```

Comment: Все-таки не имя для телеги, а nickname, он задаётся отдельно в настройках профиля.

Comment: а по номеру телефона можно?

Answer (score 6):

для Viber:

```
<a href="viber://chat?number=+38xxxxxxxxxx">
```

Answer (score 3):

**Для Whatsapp**

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=79xxxxxxxxx">
```

Answer (score 2):

Для whatsapp с сообщением:

```html
<a href="https://wa.me/79991573044?text=Здравствуйте%20Андрей!">Написать в WhatsApp</a>
```

(номер и текст который сразу ставится в поле ввода замените на свой, %20 это пробел)
Для телеграма и вайбера уже написали ответы.
P.S.: Ещё возможно у Вас не работает по той причине, что Вы пишете + перед номером телефона, этого делать НЕ нужно.